# Legend not getting Displayed in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-charts

I have legend enabled in the chart config

```
config: {
       legends: {
                  position: 'right'
                }
}
```

Also i have enabled the showInLegend config to true but legend is not being displayed...What am i missing???

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legends are available since Sencha 2.1 GA